# Hint is not displaying in jquery.Gantt chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gantt-chart

I am using [jQuery.Gantt](http://mbielanczuk.com/jquery-gantt/) plugin.
Hint on task is not displaying on mouseover event.

How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: are you getting any console error on browser?

Comment: No.. there is no console error.

Comment: Example: http://jsbin.com/vahayoju/1/edit